# GNU compile-time stack checking

Tags: g++, stack-overflow, gnu

Our application crashed immediately upon entering main with the following:

```
0x0000000000492148 in main (argc=Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7689fc)
```

After using objdump we realized there were several very large objects that were created on the stack. All this is good.

Now, we are trying to instruct g++ to inform us of such huge stack allocations at the preamble, but using -fstack-check doesn't do it in this case, possibly because the problem is in main.

I read about STACK_CHECK_BUILTIN, but is that a flag that should be provided to the compilation of g++, and not my application? The documentation is vast, but not concise.